# If longer wavelength color is perceived faster by human, what about non-spectral color (black)?

Tags: vision, human-eye, color

Related to human vision, I read the hypothesis about how longer-wavelength color is perceived faster by human eye than shorter-wavelength color [source : A Brief Classification of Colour Illusions](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228490244_A_Brief_Classification_of_Colour_Illusions). But what if the other color is a non-spectral color like, black ? Black is achromatic color, it's the absence of colors and has no wavelength. Does this perception hypothesis still apply ?

Because I've been doing a color comparison by putting a layer of colors on top of each other. In this case I tried with black - green (~549nm) and black - yellow (~570nm), and it seems like black is always dominant against other colors. But I can't find any scientific reference for this. The closest I found is the hypothesis I mentioned before. Any suggestion ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a citation for your claim about faster longer-wavelength perception. It's also not at all clear what you mean about putting a layer of colors on top of each other. If you are talking about absorbance, then yes of course, black is always going to dominate because it absorbs everything else. It doesn't matter what other color is there, when you see an object that has color that's based on the light reflected off of it. It has nothing to do with perception speed.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question. So I've been doing some kind of experiment by putting a different color pattern for each eye to see. Because human vision will see the scene from 2 eyes as a whole one, so they will perceive these 2 colors overlap with each other. What I'm trying to find out is the information about color perception according to human vision. In case if there's black in the pattern, why is it always dominant when it's overlapping with other colors ? I hope I explain clearly.

Comment: Might be nice to post some of those illusion pictures; I have an idea of what you are talking about now thanks to the link you provided, but previously it was unclear from the text. Thanks for the edits

Comment: Thanks ! I'm not sure to put one of that illusion picture. I'm afraid it will mislead because what I've been doing is quite different. Not some kind of optical illusion.

Comment: Oh okay - still it might be helpful to show what you're doing. After all, I thought you were creating illusions similar to what was on that page. It's going to be hard for someone to help you with a hypothesis if they don't know what phenomenon you are trying to hypothesize about.

Comment: That link is not about perceiving some colors faster than others, so that reference is misleading, or distracting at best. What do you mean with faster? *Quikcer*, or perhaps *better*?

Comment: I couldn't find any mention of wavelength-dependent latencies in perception